# Flutter How to make floating button like hotels.com app see all

Tags: android, ios, flutter

In Hotels app
Flutter How to make floating button like hotels.com app see all

```
TextButton(
  style: ButtonStyle(
    overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color?>(
      (Set<MaterialState> states) {
        if (states.contains(MaterialState.focused))
          return Colors.blue;
        return null; // Defer to the widget's default.
      }
    ),
  ),
  onPressed: () { },
  child: Text('See All'),
)
```

[images]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/my6HR.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sqhu.jpg
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1pA0.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by [`ScrollController`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollController-class.html) it can help you to catch the position or actually the `offset` of your scroll
Remember to use `StatefulWidget`

```
 ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController(); // this is what i was talking about 
  bool showbtn = false;
  @override
  void initState() {
    scrollController.addListener(() { // make a listener if scroll offset changed
      // print(scrollController.offset); // this is a test comment
      if (scrollController.offset >= 400) { // this check the offset i choose this number because its more close to hotel.com app but play whit this number
        setState(() {
          showbtn = true; // this set true if its in that offset, you can guess
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          showbtn = false;
        });
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView( // this is your main body 
          controller: scrollController,
          child: Container(
            height: 10000,
            width: 500,
          ),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: showbtn // now check if bool is true to show
            ? Material(
                color: Colors.blue,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(200),
                child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () {}, // your function here
                  child: const SizedBox(
                    height: kToolbarHeight,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        'See All',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            : null, // if bool was false it shows nothing 
      ),
    );
  }
```

You can play with `widget` to make it best performance as you like

[image: and here the end]

Answer (score 0):

```dart
floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
floatingActionButton: ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {},
  child: const Text('SEE ALL'),
  style: ButtonStyle(
    shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(const StadiumBorder()),
    fixedSize: MaterialStateProperty.all(
      Size(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, 48)),
  ),
),
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but does not like this if u see the button in hotels app when scrolling align the button its floating

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its helpful to you. Refer [`FloatingActionButton`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FloatingActionButton-class.html)

```
return Scaffold(
  body: Center(
    child: Text(
      'Floating Action Button Position',
    ),
  ),
  floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
  floatingActionButton: ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () {
      print('Button Pressed');
      // Write your onPressed function here
    },
    child: const Text(
      'SEE ALL',
    ),
    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
          20.0,
        ),
      ),
      minimumSize: Size(
        double.infinity,
        50,
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Your result screen-> [image]

Comment: thanks for your answer but does not like this if u see the button in hotels app when scrolling align the button its floating